# Converting XML to PHP, data sometimes returned as an array, sometimes not

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, xml

I am converting the XML returned from an API request into a PHP object, but when I do, it sometimes returns one certain part of the data as an array and sometimes not.

It makes sense— if there is more than one entry, it returns the set of that data as an array, but if there is only one, it returns only that object, rather than that one object wrapped in an otherwise empty array. This just makes it awfully hard to deal with it using JavaScript when I convert the PHP object to JSON data and pass it to the front-end, since I have to check whether the data returned is an array vs. a plain JS object.

Here is the first example:

### Example #1: Returns multiple `<field>` tags as an array under the `field` key

**PHP:***

```php
$xml = '<xml><fields><field><name>field_name</name><required>true</required></field><field><name>field_name</name><required>true</required></field></fields></xml>';
$php_obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo json_encode($php_obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Returned JSON:**

```json
{
  "fields": {
    "field": [
      {
        "name": "field_name",
        "required": "true"
      },
      {
        "name": "field_name",
        "required": "true"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

### Example #2: Returns single `<field>` tag as an object under the `field` key

**PHP:***

```php
$xml = '<xml><fields><field><name>field_name</name><required>true</required></field></fields></xml>';
$php_obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo json_encode($php_obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Returned JSON:**

```json
{
  "fields": {
    "field": {
      "name": "field_name",
      "required": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Example #3: Desired Output ✨

What I would actually desire—which I understand may require some custom work—is to always load however many `<field>` tags there are into an array of objects under the `fields` key, and omit any instance of a singular `field` key altogether.

Is there a way to force either the PHP data, once converted from XML, to replace certain keys' values with an array bound value of their contents.

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "field_name",
      "required": "true"
    }
  ]
}

// or...

{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "field_name",
      "required": "true"
    },
    {
      "name": "field_name",
      "required": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

In JavaScript, this could be done like this:

```js
const replaceFields = obj => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (key === 'fields' && obj.fields.field) obj.fields = [obj.fields.field].flat();
    else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') replaceFields(obj[key]);
  }
  return obj;
}

const sampleObj = {
  deeply: { nested: { fields: { field: {
    name: "field_name",
    required: "true"
  }}}},
  fields: { field: [
    {
      name: "field_name",
      required: "true"
    },
    {
      name: "field_name",
      required: "true"
    }
  ]}
};

replaceFields(sampleObj);
```

This correctly returns the below JSON, where both the deeply nested `fields` key wraps its single `field` key contents in an array, and also replace the object housing the `field` key in both sections with the value of the array object housed within its `field` key value accordingly.

```json
{
  "deeply": {
    "nested": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "field_name",
          "required": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "field_name",
      "required": "true"
    },
    {
      "name": "field_name",
      "required": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using PHP? If there is a way to accomplish this intelligently without having to create a manual list of keys to match for, that would be even better. Does XML provide any way of knowing which tags are "repeater tags" that can house multiple values versus unique values that will only ever house one value?

Comment: So what part of this process is _actually_ going wrong, and what [specific problem do you need help with here](/help/how-to-ask)? Because a well-focussed question shouldn't need three use cases, it just needs to cover (1) what you wanted to do, (2) what code you wrote to do that, (3) how it's misbehaving, and (4) what you already did to try to make it do the right thing.

Comment: As I understand, the problem is the php function json_encode, translate into object if the tag appear 1 time, and into array of objects if the tag appear 2 or more times, and then results into a different json structure